# Layout не масштабируется по вертикали, выходит за экран

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:background="#79c7ff"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textVieweng"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="55dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:background="#b2ff30"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textViewarab"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="70dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="ClickButton1"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="ClickButton2"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="ClickButton3"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:onClick="ClickButton4"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:onClick="ClickButton5"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:onClick="ClickButton6"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:onClick="ClickButton7"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:onClick="ClickButton8"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:onClick="ClickButton9"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:onClick="ClickButton0"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="·"
            android:id="@+id/buttondot"
            android:onClick="ClickButtondot"
            />
        <Button
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:onClick="ClickButtonC"
            android:background="#ff706b"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Для начала назначьте вес (`layout_weght`) корневого лэйаута сумме весов вложенных элементов, а лучше уберите этот параметр из корневого лэйаута вовсе

Comment: скриншот в студию!